# what is root layout in XML?

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

this is my xml file .which is pity much simple. My intention is to increase height of scroll view dynamically and the image (which is with the scroll view) view will be shown gradually.so how can i do that and What is rootLayout here and How i call rootLayout from my code ??

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run() {

                        secondCounter++;
                        yourNewHeight += 10;

                        sv.getLayoutParams().height = yourNewHeight;

                        LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)      findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
                        root.invalidate();
                        Log.v("", "" +sv.getLayoutParams().height);

                        if(secondCounter == 20){
                            timer.cancel();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, delay, period);
```

this is my code in java file.But its not working . guys can you help me out..!!!

Comment: Please note that `AbsoluteLayout` is long depreciated and you should use an alternative.

Comment: use Relative layout Instead and you dont have to increase the of the gridview give it wrap content,you have to add image dynamically in linear layout which will be under scrollview

Comment: thank you.. :-) but i cant place items properly in XMl when i use Linear Layout.

Answer (score 0):

The root of this layout is the `AbsoluteLayout`.

You can obtain a reference to this root `View` together with all of its children in your `Activity` using a call like:

```
mRootView = ((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.rootLayout));
```

Note that `AbsoluteLaoyut` is long depreciated and you will probably want to replace it with an alternative `ViewGroup`, such as a `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc. depending on the rest of your layout and how you want to do things.

Comment: since i'm new in this field , so i find easy with AbsoluteLayout. the problem which i had with LinearLayout or RelativeLayout is that , i can't place items in proper place in XMl . so i'm using it. is there any solution Mr. Trevor ???

Answer (score 0):

If you've inflated your XML appropriately in code (ie called `setContentView()`) you should be able to reference rootLayout using:

```
AbsoluteLayout root = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
```

Though if you're just trying to increase the height of the `ScrollView`, it makes more sense to directly call:

```
ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
```

And as above, you should probably use a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` rather than an `AbsoluteLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Since ScrollView can only have one Child within it, you can use ScrollView itself as your root element with a LinearLayout as a direct and only child to it, inside which u can add any views you want.

And AbsoluteLayout is deprecated, and I'd recommend not to use it